# Kql equivalent functions

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql, appinsights

I'm trying to manipulate the contents of fields returned from application Insights logging and was wondering if there are KQL equivalents for the Oracle `substr` and `instr` functions?

Comment: Plenty of [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/substringfunction) available regarding the available functions.

Comment: Better describe a clear scenario and ask for a solution without trying to dictate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of Oracle substr function in KQL is [substring()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/substringfunction).

The equivalent of Oracle instr function in KQL is [indexof()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/indexoffunction).